# Max weight bipartite matching problem with variable cost matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

I see following is the standard max weight bipartite matching problem,

> \begin{align}
> \max_{X} &\sum_{i,j} C_{i,j} X_{i,j} \\
> \mathrm{s.t.}& \\
>  &\sum_i X_{i,j} = 1 \\
>  &\sum_j X_{i,j} = 1 
> \end{align}

In my problem, the cost matrix $C$ is also a variable matrix, with following linear constraints;
\begin{equation}
A c \leq b
\end{equation}
where $c=\mathrm{vec}(C)$, is vectorized form of matrix $C$. That is, each column of matrix $C$ is taken and appended together to create vector $c$.

So, my problem is as follows,

> \begin{align}
> \max_{X,C} &\sum_{i,j} C_{i,j} X_{i,j} \\
> \mathrm{s.t.}& \\
>  &\sum_i X_{i,j} = 1 \\
>  &\sum_j X_{i,j} = 1 \\
>  & \hspace{0.5cm} A c \leq b 
> \end{align}

Can anyone help me please?